# Removing ' from strings in list

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to remove or ignore the `'` symbol (Apostrophe) within a list of strings. I don't know if my for loop is just plain wrong or what:

```
n = ["a", "a's", "aa's"] #example list

for i in n:
    i.strip("'")
```

Comment: `.strip` only removes from the start and end of the string, [as documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip). Also note that it returns a new string, so the list wouldn't have changed anyway.

Comment: Also calling`strip` achieves nothing unless you do something with its return value.

Comment: just do `n = [x.replace("'", "") for x in n]`. `strip` does not work here for the reasons explained in the above comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strip` won't work here use `replace`,

```
In [9]: [i.replace("'",'') for i in lst]
Out[9]: ['a', 'as', 'aas']
```

Answer (score 1):

Two problems here.

- First, `strip` doesn't work in the middle of the string, you have to use `replace("'", "")
- Second, and more important, *strings are immutable*. Even if `i.strip(...)` did what you want, it would not *change* `i`. It would just produce a new string. So, you have to store that string.

Sum up, try something like

```
n = [i.replace("'", "") for i in n]
```